# PHP Sandbox environment

Tags: php, scripting, external, sandbox

I'm not sure if the question title is apt.

Is there any possible way to deploy a sandbox php environment that will execute scripts and output results that runs separately from the actual php instance that processes your site.

This is in order to allow external users to upload and execute their custom php scripts without posing a security risk to the main website.

Comment: Is it relevant if the scripts get executed in a web or a CLI environment?

Comment: No its not. Fine either way.

Comment: A secure and scalable approach would be to use `docker` to execute each script inside a separate container. That way you have a standardized environment (even multiple, if required) and a strict separation between host and container. see https://www.docker.com/

Comment: Can you, yes. But it's REALLY hard. You could also just use something like this: https://github.com/Viper-7/Deployable-PHP-Codepad

Answer (score 2):

You can install multiple PHP instances and run Apache in a jail.

- http://mossiso.com/2009/09/02/multiple-php-instances-with-one-apache.html
- http://www.linux-faqs.info/apache/running-apache-in-chroot-jail

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can have them run in a sandbox or a `chroot` environment. No, there is no way to do this that is safe and secure.

You need to look at more than just the server. Also think about cookies. Any of these scripts will also be able to read and set cookies of your domain. If a user is logged into "/admin" on your domain (as an example) then one of these custom scripts will be sent the session identifier for that login and the custom script could send it to an attacker to do malicious things to your site.

Run the uploaded scripts run on a different server and use a different domain.